# Mapbox keeps GPS Lock after app is the background on Android

Tags: android, gps, location, mapbox

I Want to use mapbox in an app we are building so far it running good, but I keep noticing that even when the app has gone to the background the phone still has a GPS lock.

Im using the Mapview component in a fragment and in the initialization 
of the mapview I'm creating a `UserLocationOverlay` with the `GpsLocationProvider` and I call the method `enableMyLocation()` on it.

So I assume I also have to call `myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();` in the `onPause` life-cycle method  for when the fragment is not shown on the screen. which should also disable the GPS lock.

How ever when I leave the app or make it go to the background the GPS fix icon remains in statusbar and stays there till a kill the app from the recent app switcher.

How can I fix this. Below some initialization code and the onResume, onPause methods

```
private void initMap() {
    mMapView.setDiskCacheEnabled(true);
    mMapView.setCenter(mLatLng);
    mMapView.setZoom(ZOOM_LEVEL);

    // Adds an icon that shows location
    myLocationOverlay = new UserLocationOverlay(new GpsLocationProvider(getActivity()), mMapView);
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    mMapView.addOverlay(myLocationOverlay);

    List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>(mPoints.size());
    for (Point point : mPoints) {
        // create some markers and add them to the map.
    }

    mMapView.addItemizedOverlay(new ItemizedIconOverlay(getActivity(), markers, new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<Marker>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(int position, Marker marker) {
            // set some click logic
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongPress(int i, Marker marker) {
            return false;
        }
    }));
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (myLocationOverlay != null && !myLocationOverlay.isMyLocationEnabled()) {
        myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (myLocationOverlay != null) {
        if (myLocationOverlay.isMyLocationEnabled()) {
            myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't have to disable the MyLocationOverlay when in the lifecycle methods onResume/onPause. The Mapbox SDK seems to handle that for you.

Comment: have u succesfully added UserLocationOverlay .. in your code i m getting error when trying to show users current location on map